# Magento1.9 - Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity'(PCI compliance)

Tags: javascript, magento1.9.2.4, pci

I have generated the SHA-256 and added in the integrity tag like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-65DEQpj8HBSb+/YImG+9LCeuQeRkm5NMpJWTH6hSuFZ+" src="example.com/media/js/90a8720cd608ccab8eaf40398728caf8.js">
```

I am getting the below error in the console:

> Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for
>   resource 'example.com/media/js/90a8720cd608ccab8eaf40398728caf8.js'
>   with computed SHA-256 integrity
>   "65DEQpj8HBSb+/YImG+9LCeuQeRkm5NMpJWTH6hSuFZ+" The resource has been
>   blocked.

***I have also tried with SHA-384 and SHA-512.***

Thanks.

Comment: the script you draw in(maybe in CDN) has changed.But your html used integrity to ensure the file not changed....

Comment: try with <script src="example.com/media/js/90a8720cd608ccab8eaf40398728caf8.js" integrity="sha256-65DEQpj8HBSb+/YImG+9LCeuQeRkm5NMpJWTH6hSuFZ+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: The file name is the same. I have tried with attribute crossorigin="anonymous", but still getting the same error.